# C++ binary search tree implementation, dynamic array or structs/class?

Tags: c++, struct, binary-search-tree, dynamic-arrays

I'm tasked with implementing a binary search tree and was going the usual struct route:

```
struct Node { 
    int value;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
    Node( int val ) {
     ...
    }
}
```

When I thought about implementing it using a dynamic array and using arithmetic to figure out the left and right nodes. My question is will an array implementation change the time and space complexity of the operations (insert, delete, inorder walk, et al.) for better or worse?

I can see how the delete operation might be an issue, reorganize the array and keep the tree's structure, but the tree size is small, a hundred nodes max.

Comment: Just use `std::map` or `std::set`

Comment: Don't you mean `Node * left` and `Node * right`?

Comment: As you stated, the memory efficiency will be better. Right now, each Node has itself plus a pointer, which takes 64bit in a 64bit system. With an index, it will only hold additional information of the size of an integer or whatever. And as you stated, delete will be somewhat problematic. What you can do, of course, would be to let deleted Nodes stay in the vector/array/whatever and only tidy them up when necessary (too many deleted nodes existing), with them having some invalid value to mark them as deleted.

Comment: By the way, don't label this C++ *and* C. It's one of those. And I'd make Node as an inner class within the actual tree, with private pointers. This is because there is a high chance that you will return a Node pointer at some point in time, and right now, changing that one might render your tree inconsistent, no matter whether you use pointers or indices inside of it.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm trying to code this from scratch, besides map and set would essentially be another struct implementation no?

Comment: @Aziuth wouldn't leaving those deleted nodes lead to bad insert operations i.e. inserting a node under a deleted but not cleaned up root? Sorry about the labeling, but this is for C++.

Comment: @mand Why would it? You simply insert by taking the next free (including deleted) position. By the way, what do you mean by root? Usually, the root of a tree is the first Node, but in your code, every Node has a root that is clearly not a pointer? Do you mean value?

Comment: @azuith Yes, corrected. That makes sense, the tree would still keep its structure if you always insert at the nearest empty node as opposed to leftmost or rightmost node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the time and space complexity of the operations (insert, delete, inorder walk, et al.) change?

Inserting and removing from non-leaf nodes in an array-based tree will require moving all elements that come after it in the array. This changes the complexity from O(log n) to O(n log n).

> will an array implementation be a better use of memory than using structs?

Yes, without a doubt. Array based trees are friendlier to the cache and take fewer allocations, plus there's no requirement to store pointers per node.